# Including external javascript in shopify page from the app installed using shopify api

Tags: javascript, php, shopify

I am new to shopify and just created one shopify development account, created one app. I have provided option for each user to install my app using their shopify shop name. So how can I include one of my javascript file(customized in my app) in their shopify page? Like I want to load my javascript file in their shopify page (this js file is for loading one popup for subscription). Do there any shopify api for loading this specific js file from my app to their shop page?

I used the following link for reference,

https://github.com/cmcdonaldca/ohShopify.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ScriptTag resource: https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/scripttag

This is from the Shopify website:

> If you need to add anything to a storefront use JavaScript. Don't edit a theme's files. Add your JavaScript using a ScriptTag resource. When your app is uninstalled, your Javascript will no longer be used by the shop automatically, and that is the beauty of using a ScriptTag resource. The merchant won't need to edit his theme to bring it back to the way it was before your app's installation.

Comment: Ok... I will try this.

Comment: When I authorize with my live url I am getting a 400 Oauth error saying

 Oauth error invalid_request: The redirect_uri is missing or not whitelisted

Is that because it is having http??

Comment: It is fixed. But still getting 500 internal server error

Comment: if I want load at shopify app page (admin side), how can I do?